# how do i create auto increment sub collection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around this.

I want to save an auto incremented list of forms submitted per user.

I'm trying to achieve a scheme something like:

```
users:{
    _id:asfa98s7fasf,
    name:"some name",
    forms:{
       1:{
           _id:asdasdfa8sdf,
           q1:'yes',
           q2:'no',
           q3:'yes'
       }, 
       2:{
           _id:asdasdfgdfgf,
           q1:'no',
           q2:'no',
           q3:'yes'
       }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to create the auto incrementing forms.

I think i need to use ensureIndex someplace but I'm just not sure.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do this in 2 operations :

1. Find total elements in the forms array using a query, N
2. Use another update query to add one more item to form array, with key being "K+1" .

You can also try using non assosiative array to store elements in form document, unless , your keys are having some special purpose , eg :

```
users:{
    _id:asfa98s7fasf,
    name:"some name",
    forms:[
       {
           _id:asdasdfa8sdf,
           q1:'yes',
           q2:'no',
           q3:'yes'
       }, 
       {
           _id:asdasdfgdfgf,
           q1:'no',
           q2:'no',
           q3:'yes'
       ]
    }

}
```

Then you can use `$push` operator to add element to `form` array, which will automatically be appended at position 3 of the array.
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push

Comment: Thank you. I knew an array could be worked in some how. This helps a lot!